# how to add one parametar for a function using kotlin symbol processing(KSP)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-symbol-processing

I have an annotation "AddHeader" for functions:

```
annotation class AddHeader
```

If one function adds this annotation, it will add a parameter like this:

```
// service for retrofit
interface TestService {
    @AddHeader
    @Get("show")
    fun show(a: Int)
}
```

will change:

```
// service for retrofit
interface TestService {
    @Get("show")
    fun show(@retrofit2.http.Header("custom_key") header : String = "", a: Int)
}
```

I hava no idea how to get this goal. Please help.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think this is possible with KSP. KSP can only be used to generate a new code, not modify the existing one. You would need to write a full compiler plugin.

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much.